# Multiple components in same page using singe app in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

How to render a part of html from child to parent in Angular2.
The idea is to make a main layout and sections of this layout are overridden(filled) by children based on the requirements.
I've tried aux. routes but I couldn't make it work.
PS: I wouldn't like this part to have it's own route since it's just a part of the page.
Latest Angular2 please!

For example

```html
<div class="layout">
    <div class="page-header">
        //Another router outlet here (How to render also this part for each child seperate)
        //Some children will have custom page header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        //content from child is rendered here
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not want the specific route for the individual template then you can achieve this as follows.

Assuming on load you are bootstraping appComponent.

app.component.html

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="page-header">
        //Another router outlet here (How to render also this part for each child seperate)
        //Some children will have custom page header
        <router-outlet name='child1'></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        //content from child is rendered here
        <router-outlet name='child2'></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add following to your router.

```
{
    path: 'home',  // you can keep it empty if you do not want /home
    component: 'appComponent',
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: childOneComponent,
            outlet: 'child1'
        },
        {
            path: '',
            component: childTwoComponent,
            outlet: 'child2'
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when /home is loaded appComponent will get load with allocated template, then angular router will check the route and load the children component in specified router outlet on the basis of name.